# Annotation in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, annotation

How does the annotation work in the VSE, in blender 2.8 beta? If I check the box annotation in the VSE and add a layer nothing happens. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After adding a layer. Hold D to draw on VSE preview window.
Holding D and drawing with right click will bring up the eraser.You can turn on Onion Skinning in the options panel as well.

Comment: Does it only work in the preview window, and not in the sequencer?

Comment: If you mean the window with the actual video strips.. Then no. You can only draw in the preview window or in the 3d viewport as far as i know.

Comment: Get 2.83 and there will be a toolbar with an annotation tool in the preview.